# Jumper wire on a light switch box and I'm not sure what else

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

While painting the living room the light switch cover was off. None of the switches are using the green ground screw. There is a jumper wire between switches, on the hot side. All the green wires are twisted together. The  white wires are connected together off the switches.

I'm not sure what's going on. Or if it's safe. I'm in the US

Any help would be great.

[image]

Comment: Yes sorry I'm in the us. That's what I thought too. I've never seen this before.

Comment: Normally the sheathing of the wire is stripped back to the strain relief where the wire enters the box.  You'd have a ground wire pigtailed from the devices (switches) back to the ground wire bundle.  I can't tell for sure but it looks like there are two wires under the switch screw on the right - I don't think that is allowed.  The wire on the first switch seems to be coming out from the screw.  You normally see bare grounds in device boxes.

Comment: Is there no concern that one of those floating bare earths is going to contact one of the enormous exposed screws as you push the face-plate into the back box, especially as your patress screws are directly connected to all that metal?? It's all just so very very … dangerous & exposed. Electrical tape is for when you have absolutely no alternative, not for 'everyday' use, where it's going to harden & the glue will go off just in time for next you need to take the plate off...

Comment: @Tetsujin -- this mess isn't up to Code anywhere in the US either, let me tell you that

Comment: Ugh ‍♂️ the box is plastic. If that works. How can I fix this? I know basic wiring. I can put a switch in, dimmer, lights etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The jumper between switches is fine, but you need to fix that grounding

The jumper carrying always-hot from switch to switch is considered normal practice in the US, but your switches need to be grounded, and because they're mounted to a plastic box, that *must* occur via ground wires as the switches can't pick up ground from the box.  So, you'll need to use a proper wirenut (one of the 8-port push-in units will definitely do the trick) to bundle all those grounding wires from your cables together with 12AWG grounding pigtails from the green switch grounding screws.